# map[Task]int64 where Task is an interface

Tags: dictionary, go, identity

Let's say I define the following interface in a Go library:

```
type Task interface {
    Do() error
}

func Register(task Task) { ... }

func GetId(task Task) int64 { ... }
```

In `Register()`, the library associates a unique `int64` with each task instance. `GetId()` must return the identifier for the given task.

My initial idea was to store the association as a `map[Task]int64`. This seems to work fine, but I was told that it would break if an object implementing `Task` was not equality-comparable (for example, a `struct` containing a `map`). I still need to check if this is true.

I was going to try and use a slice of `struct { task Task; id int64 }` instead and just iterate over it, but that would still require equality comparable `Task` instances. And AFAIU there is no identity comparison in Go.

How can I have a robust mapping from `Task` instances to their ID?

EDIT: Both solutions proposed so far work, but they have the disadvantage that every Task implementation has to include some repetitive code to handle the IDs. I could provide that code in a TaskBase `struct` that could be embedded, but ideally I would prefer a solution that doesn't require implementations to even know about the IDs (they are internal to the library and have no meaning outside of it).

Comment: Why not use the more simple `map[int64]Task`?

Comment: Because I need to find the ID of a given task, and not the opposite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more complete example:  http://play.golang.org/p/1RzDiw7F9t

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

type Task interface {
    Do() error
    ID() int64
}

type XTask struct {
    id int64
    // other stuff
}

func NewXTask( /*task parameters...*/) *XTask {
    t := &XTask{ /*initialize members*/}
    t.id = Register(t)
    // possibly more initialization...
    return t
}

func (t *XTask) Do() error  { return nil }  // stub
func (t *XTask) ID() int64  { return t.id }

var taskRegistry = map[int64]Task{}

func Register(t Task) int64 {
    var id int64
    for {
        id = rand.Int63()
        if _, exists := taskRegistry[id]; !exists {
            break
        }
    }
    taskRegistry[id] = t
    return id
}

func main() {
    t1 := NewXTask()
    t2 := NewXTask()
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", t1.ID())
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", t2.ID())
}
```

I used an ID method as Daniel suggested, and I turned the map backwards from the way you had it.  This is because the Task objects know their own ID, so a map from Task to ID is not needed.  A map from ID to task however, is useful for guaranteeing uniqueness.  It might come in handy some other time if you find yourself with only an ID and you need the corresponding Task object.

Also note this example is not goroutine-safe.  If you need that you will have to add synchronization.

Comment: That would indeed work, thank you. What bothers me is that this solution requires all implementations of Task to have code to handle the ID (even if it's only a few lines).

Comment: Well, you can use embedding, as in http://play.golang.org/p/n8C1nz-SWN, but in my opinion that increases the complexity of the code a bit, just in the interest of saving a few lines.

Comment: Yes, that's what I suggested in my edit of the question. Note that many Task implementations will be written by many people, so the savings can be significant. I'm still trying to find a way to do this without needing code in the implementations.

Comment: Any mapping from Task to anything is going to require Tasks to be somehow comparable for equality.  (Not necessarily with the == operator, it could be done with some function.)  How would you like to define equality?  Storing a unique ID with each Task allows this to be done simply.  An alternative might be to hash some unchanging data stored in the task, but you already mentioned that each task would have an associated ID.  Maybe this ID is for some other purpose, but if it is already defined to be unique why not use it to define task equality as well?

Comment: For this purpose, I would like to define equality as identity, i.e. "points to the same object as". But there's no such thing in Go, is there? If I have two variables of type `Task`, can I determine if both point to the exact same instance?

Comment: Not easily.  As a general observation, you could be trying too hard to fit your concepts from other programming languages into Go.  While you can often force code to fit like this, the result turns out overly complex.  It might be time to step back and look at the overall program requirements and how to most idiomatically implement them in Go.  Requirements are rarely so specific as to mention types and data structures.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the standard answer (excuse?) of Go's "inner circle". In this case, all suggested solutions are arguably more complex than using object identity comparison, if such a thing existed (but maybe there are good technical reasons why this would be difficult to implement in Go). Anyway, thank you for your time.